# "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" when no constraints exist in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I started receiving the following when running on an iPhone SE using OS 9.3.1

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x145d510c0 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x145d4f4e0]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x145d47bf0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x145d47140 'UIInputWindowController-top' V:|-(0)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x145d4f4e0]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x145d47bf0 )>"
```

I had no problems in the simulator (using iPhone 5). I can't ignore it as when I seque to another view controller the app crashes.

I pared back all UI elements to none but still got this error. I stopped the code by using Debug View Hierarchy but none of the UIView constraint references match the constraints listed in the error.

Comment: I think you can ignore these, but you should put the details of your crash

Comment: I'm recreating my project from scratch - I have all the code and all the UI elements need to be readded anyway :-(  At the moment, with just some simple elements added, I get the same constraints error but the app does not crash as it was doing before.

Comment: I have seen that constraints error too. I think it is a side effect of debugging or something.  That is why I suggest you ignore it